# issue with password matching

Tags: php, html, validation

The following is my php code.
I'm trying to make a form validation for registration, everything seems fine when I submit my form without filling in all the field. And when i try to fill up everything but purposely to mismatch the passwords, it somehow still allows me to register successfully.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
        if (empty($_POST['useremail']))
            $newemailerr = "Email is required!";
        else 
            $newemail = ($_POST['useremail']);

        if (empty($_POST['userid']))
            $newiderr = "Username is required!";
        else 
            $newid = ($_POST['userid']);

        if (empty($_POST['userpass']))
            $newpasserr = "Password is required!";
        else 
            $newpass = ($_POST['userpass']);

        if (empty($_POST['confirmpass'] && $_POST['confirmpass'] != $_POST['userpass']))
            $newconfirmpasserr = "Both passwords do not match!";
        else 
            $newconfirmpass = ($_POST['confirmpass']);
    }
```

Comment: please check this line (empty($_POST['confirmpass'] && $_POST['confirmpass'] != $_POST['userpass']))

Comment: I think it should be if (!empty($_POST['confirmpass']) && !empty($_POST['userpass']) && $_POST['confirmpass'] != $_POST['userpass'])

Comment: @vSugumar it doesnt help at all :(

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a validation library.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    if (empty($_POST['useremail']))
        $newemailerr = "Email is required!";
    else 
        $newemail = ($_POST['useremail']);

    if (empty($_POST['userid']))
        $newiderr = "Username is required!";
    else 
        $newid = ($_POST['userid']);

    if (empty($_POST['userpass']))
        $newpasserr = "Password is required!";
    else 
        $newpass = ($_POST['userpass']);

  if (empty($_POST['confirmpass']) || $_POST['confirmpass'] != $_POST['userpass'])            $newconfirmpasserr = "Both passwords do not match!";
    else 
        $newconfirmpass = ($_POST['confirmpass']);
}
```

you should use OR here

```
 if (empty($_POST['confirmpass']) || $_POST['confirmpass'] != $_POST['userpass'])
```

Comment: Yes, the other problem is the empty() isn't closed until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified (DRY) assuming your PHP version supports it - you can push the errors and return only once if you wish

```
 $newemail       = $_POST['useremail']   ?? "";
 $newid          = $_POST['userid']      ?? "";
 $newpass        = $_POST['userpass']    ?? "";
 $newconfirmpass = $_POST['confirmpass'] ?? "";

 if (trim($newemail)          == "") { echo "Email is required!";        die(0); }
 if (trim($newid)             == "") { echo "Username is required!";     die(0); }
 if (trim($newpass            == "") { echo "Password is required!";     die(0); }
 if (trim($newconfirmpass)    == "") { echo "New password is required!"; die(0); }
 if ($newpass != $newconfirmpass   ) { echo "Passwords do not match!";   die(0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the last if function you have an incorrect assumption. If you use `&&` after entering the function (after fulfilling the conditions of the function) it should be `$ newconfirmpass = ($ _POST ['confirmpass']`you have `$ newconfirmpasserr = "Both passwords do not match!";` (Swapping the actions in this function with outside this function). Of course, this solution would have a flaw in the logic of the structure of the whole function, because you have a message in the body of any conditional function. I suggest replacing `&&` to `||` (`and` on `or`). This will solve the problem.

The code does not validate input data. I understand that it is in the further part of the code (controller) or on the fronted aplication - validation at the html level and / or javascript.

It is worth mentioning that such a construction (the main function) violates the principles of **DRY** and **Open/closed** and the naming of variables break the rule of **PSR1** - the principles of good software development. In the first case of **DRY** - you can use the solution proposed by @mplungjan user. **Open/closed** - rather requires refactoring on the object style. **PSR1** - I suggest using camelCase.

The code shows the tendency of procedural programming, which complicates further work with the code. I recomendet you refactoring this code to the object model.

It is also not recommended to pass parameters or message in one variable. A good solution is to use two associative arrays (there can also be collections or objects) -  one for variables, the other for sending messages. This will keep the code in order - at this stage as well as its future development.